# Using BasicPrimitives: How to add child to a famdiagram?

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to use [BasicPrimitives](http://www.basicprimitives.com/) to make a family tree application, but I can't seem to refresh the diagram with fresh data after adding a new child :)

```
items.push(newItem);
```

works, but I have to click on one item so that the whole diagram would refresh and show the newly added item

when I try to use the update tree function I get no results:

```
 jQuery("#basicdiagram").famDiagram("update", primitives.famdiagram.UpdateMode.Refresh);
```

also this didn't get me anywhere as well:

```
jQuery("#basicdiagram2").orgDiagram({
       items: items,
       cursorItem: newItem.id
});
```

Any help would be great :)

EDIT: this is the code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Adding new items at run time</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/js/jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/primitives.min.js"></script>
    <link href="demo/css/primitives.latest.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

        $(window).load(function () {
            var options = new primitives.famdiagram.Config();
            var maximumId = 5;

            var items = [
                 new primitives.famdiagram.ItemConfig({ id: 1,parents: null, title: "Thomas Williams", label: "Thomas Williams", description: "4, VP, Server & Tools Marketing and Solutions", phone: "904-547-5342", email: "thomwill@name.com", image: "demo/images/photos/r.png", itemTitleColor: "#4b0082" }),

              new primitives.famdiagram.ItemConfig( { id: 2, parents: null, title: "Sara Kemp", label: "Sara Kemp", description: "15, VP, Software & Enterprise Management Division", phone: "918-257-4218", email: "sarakemp@name.com", image: "demo/images/photos/g.png", itemTitleColor: "#4b0082" })

            ];



            var buttons = [];
            buttons.push(new primitives.famdiagram.ButtonConfig("delete", "ui-icon-close", "Delete"));
            buttons.push(new primitives.famdiagram.ButtonConfig("properties", "ui-icon-gear", "Info"));
            buttons.push(new primitives.famdiagram.ButtonConfig("add", "ui-icon-person", "Add"));
            options.items = items;
            var panel = jQuery("#panel");
            var orgchartform = panel.find("[name=orgchartform]")

            options.cursorItem = 0;
            options.linesWidth = 1;
            options.linesColor = "black";
            options.hasSelectorCheckbox = primitives.common.Enabled.True;
            options.lineItemsInterval = 5;
            options.buttons = buttons;
            options.hasButtons = primitives.common.Enabled.True;
            options.hasSelectorCheckbox = primitives.common.Enabled.False;


            options.onButtonClick = function (e, data) {

                if(data.name == 'add')
                {

                                var items = jQuery("#basicdiagram2").famDiagram("option", "items");


                                var newItem = new primitives.famdiagram.ItemConfig(
                                  {
                                      id: 3,
                                      parents: [1, 2],
                                      title: "title",
                                      label: "Name",
                                      description: "15, VP, Management Division",
                                      phone: "918-257-4218",        
                                      itemTitleColor: "#4b0082" 

                                  });  

                                items.push(newItem);

                  }

            };

            jQuery("#basicdiagram2").famDiagram(options);

        });//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>


  <div id="basicdiagram2" style="width: 640px; height: 480px; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you put sample code into js fiddle

Comment: sorry couldn't find proper references to include so I edited the post with the whole code :)

Comment: How extensively are you using the family tree? I've been using it pretty heavily. I've stumbled upon an issue and was wondering if you have the same. I'm deleting nodes and re-parenting. After doing the refresh, everything works in one environment but freezes in another. Have you been using this extensively?

Comment: sorry I haven't been active for a while ... I did not have such case, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deal was to do the following

```
jQuery("#basicdiagram").famDiagram("update", primitives.orgdiagram.UpdateMode.Refresh);
```

instead of

```
jQuery("#basicdiagram").famDiagram("update", primitives.famdiagram.UpdateMode.Refresh);
```

and the diagram refreshed successfully :)

the refresh directive

```
primitives.orgdiagram.UpdateMode.Refresh
```

obviouslyworks for all as orgdiagram